# Java code on descending order

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class StrictDescending {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int SENTINEL = 1000 ;
    int firstValue = in.nextInt();

    if (firstValue <1000)
    {

        int secondValue = firstValue ;
        secondValue = in.nextInt() ;
        while(secondValue < firstValue)
        {
            if(firstValue > secondValue)
            {
                System.out.println("Yes, the list is in descending order.") ;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("No, the list is not in descending order.") ;
            }
            secondValue = in.nextInt();
        }    
    }
}
```

> Given a list of three digit integer numbers, make sure that the numbers in the list are in strictly descending order. The output from the program should be “Yes, the list is in descending order.” or “No, the list is not in descending order.” If a number in the list is found to be out of order, then your program should stop at that point and generate the output “No, the numbers are not in descending order.” Consecutive numbers that are equal are not to be considered in descending order

With inputs:

```
150
130
120
1000
```

my code outputs

```
Yes, the list is in descending order.
Yes, the list is in descending order.
```

Comment: Your input isn't a list of three-digit integers, so I don't see anything wrong with your output.

Comment: how is 150 130 120 not a list of three digit integers

Comment: with 1000 as a stop value

Comment: @user6451702 1000 isn't a 3-digit integer.

Comment: It looks like `1000` is intended to be used as EOF, for some reason.

Comment: @user6451702 why not just use `scanner.hasNextInt()` to detect whether or not there is another number to read?

Comment: sorry the program should stop running when a 3 digit integer is not used

Comment: There are a few problems with your code.  The first problem is that you will output the Yes/No conditional after comparing the first and second values and the first and third values.  The second is that you are only comparing that the latter values are less than your first value.  THe third is that your "no" will never get executed as you have already evaluated that condition as a breakout condition, so it will not reach that code.

Comment: The list is indeed in descending order, isn't it? What's the problem here?

Comment: @TamasRev, the problem is the two outputs with the answer, instead of just one. Also, even if this list wasn't in descending order, it would never print a "no".

Answer (score 1):

If you find two numbers out of order then you can immediately declare the list is not in descending order. The converse is not true: if you find two numbers in order you don't know if the list as a whole is ordered.

Your program prints a decision as soon as it's read the first two numbers. You need to delay the "Yes, the list is in descending order." printout until you've examined all of the numbers.

Comment: so how do i go about waiting to enter more numbers? this is where i am stuck

Comment: I'm refraining from showing you what the corrected code would look like as you won't learn much from that. It's best if you figure out how to fix your code on your own.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like a homework question, which means I'm somewhat hesitant to answer it. So, I'm not going to provide any code, but I will suggest an approach:

1. Read in the first number and store is as some `previousValue`
2. While you have more numbers, load them in as `currentValue`
3. If `currentValue` is greater than `previousValue`, stop. The answer is no.
4. Otherwise, set `previousValue` equal to `currentValue` and continue the loop.
5. If the end of the loop is reached (i.e. you reach your sentinel), and you haven't already stopped and exited, then you know the answer is yes.

Or, to put it another way: look for any number that is greater than the one before it. If you find one, the list is not in descending order. If you don't find one AFTER you've run out of numbers, then it is.

Comment: Good luck. Just make sure you understand what you're actually doing, rather than following directions to "make it go".

This kind of logical problem solving is the absolute core of computer science.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the your logic. After you enter you 1000 your code checks the expression in your while statement and, because it 130 > 1000 evaluates to false it exits without printing the "No" statement.

This code will produces the desired outcome.

```
int secondValue;
            do {
                secondValue = in.nextInt();
                if (firstValue > secondValue) {
                    System.out.println("Yes, the list is in descending order.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No, the list is not in descending order.");
                }
            } while (secondValue < firstValue);
```

Comment: that code gives Yes, the list is in descending order.
Yes, the list is in descending order.
No, the list is not in descending order